# Celery Alternatives based on DAG

Tags: celery, dask, task-queue

I am building a product that uses Kubernetes. Now a user can submit requests to this cluster, which kicks off a bunch of potentially long-running tasks. I initially had intended to use Celery for this purpose: submit a bunch of tasks to other microservices. However, the crucial part is that the tasks depend on one another (I construct a DAG with the task dependencies dynamically for each request). I have found Celery to be lacking in support for general DAGs. The `group` and `chain` do some of this but it is not generic enough.

Now I am struggling to find a Celery alternative that is similarly lightweight, but allows me to submit tasks based on a DAG.
The alternatives I considered:

1. Apache Airflow: Native support for DAGs but is based on more fixed workflows, and constructing DAGs dynamically seems to be a bit of a second-class citizen.
2. Dask: This seems like it may be able to do the trick, but also seems overkill for just submitting some HTTP requests to other micro services.
3. Argo: Kubernetes-based, which is nice, but again seems overkill to spin up new kubernetes pods just to submit some HTTP requests.
4. Prefect: would still use Dask under the hood (I believe) and I do not need all the additional features.

Which alternatives should I consider instead? Also feel free to point out if my conclusions about the alternatives I considered are not accurate.

I often use Python, but will happily consider a tool based on a different language.

Comment: My suggestion to you is to pick any (I say start with Celery as it is one of the easy ones on that list) and make solution that somewhat works, instead of thinking too much ahead and trying to figure out potential problems. If you write your Celery tasks as functions that you can easily call outsite Celery context (that is how I do it) you are 100% sure you can easily move to any other technology at any point of time. KISS principle.

Comment: Appreciate that comment! That was my initial plan as well, but beyond the inherit inefficiency of not scheduling jobs as a DAG, Celery seems to really struggle with using groups() and chains() together, reliably. Hence my looking for alternatives.